# Replace nan values in a list with another value following the element data type

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of lists which might have nan values that I want to replace with another value. The problem is the elements might have different types. For example:

```
dict_of_list = {"1": ["a", "b", nan, "z], "2": [1, 4, 5, nan], "3": [60.0, nan, 40.0, 10.0]}
```

I want to replace nan with -1000 and this should follow the other elements type, hence:

```
dict_of_list = {"1": ["a", "b", "-1000", "z], "2": [1, 4, 5, -1000], "3": [60.0, -1000.0, 40.0, 10.0]}
```

I don't want to convert it to pandas and want to keep it as list. I tried

```
for name, val in dict_to_list.items():
    dict_to_list[name] = list(map(
        lambda x: -1000 if np.isnan(x) else x, val
    ))
```

but `np.isnan` won't work with string. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The way to check here for `NaN`s would be `i != i`:

```
{k: [type(next(x for x in v if x == x))(-1000) if i != i else i for i in v] for k, v in dict_of_list.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'1': ['a', 'b', '-1000', 'z'], '2': [1, 4, 5, -1000], '3': [60.0, -1000.0, 40.0, 10.0]}
```

Notice I use `type(next(x for x in v if x == x))(-1000)` to have the same type.

Comment: will this fail if the first element of v is nan?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

dict_of_list   = {"1": ["a", "b", np.nan, "z"],
                  "2": [1, 4, 5, np.nan],
                  "3": [60.0, np.nan, 40.0, 10.0]}

for key, val in dict_of_list.items():
    for item in val:
        if item is np.nan:
            val[val.index(item)] = type(val[0])(-1000)


print(dict_of_list)    

# assuming each list within the dictionary will have a single type
# assuming the very first element of the list is not a null value
```